# Add meaningful data to UDP packet inet/omnet

Tags: c++, udp, simulation, omnet++, inet

I want to add payload data or message to UDP packet.

```
    void UdpBasicApp::sendPacket()
{   
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << packetName << "-" << numSent;
    Packet *packet = new Packet(str.str().c_str());
    if(dontFragment)
        packet->addTag<FragmentationReq>()->setDontFragment(true);
    const auto& payload = makeShared<ApplicationPacket>();
    payload->setChunkLength(B(par("messageLength")));

    payload->setSequenceNumber(numSent);
    payload->addTag<CreationTimeTag>()->setCreationTime(simTime());
    packet->insertAtBack(payload);
    L3Address destAddr = chooseDestAddr();
    emit(packetSentSignal, packet);
    socket.sendTo(packet, destAddr, destPort);
    numSent++;
}
```

This is the UDP source code of inet framework for sending the packet any ideas on how to add a test message or numeric data.

Comment: The test message or numeric data is called the *payload*

Comment: What library are you using? What is a Packet or a FragmentationReq? Why dou you use new and not make_unique?

Comment: The thing is, this is the implementation of send packet defined by the inet framework

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it , you can create the packet with a name and content, the first code creates it with just the name

```
  auto rawBytesData = makeShared<BytesChunk>(); // 10 raw bytes
  rawBytesData->setBytes({243, 74, 19, 84, 81, 134, 216, 61, 4, 8});
  Packet *packet = new Packet(str.str().c_str(), rawBytesData);
```